# Grabbing the last number in a string

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

How do I grab the last number in a stored variable or string?

For example, I stored the string "1 out of 28" to "out"

Heres what I got on Selenium so far

```
storeText   xpath=/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]   out
storeEval   parseInt(storedVars['out'])   out1
echo   ${out1}
```

It echoed 1. I want to grab that number (1) and the last number (28) to compare it with something later on.

How do I grab 28 from the string?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the answer.

```
storeEval   '${out}'.split(' ').last()   result
```